# Concatenate specific values from a cell with specific values from another cell into a particular format

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula, concatenation

[image]

```
          A                       B                                       C
1       numbers                  signs                                **Result**
2    *001*                 *alpha*                       001-alpha
3    *001*111*221*104*     *alpha*kappa*epislon*ETA*     001-alpha, 111-kappa, 221-epislon, 104-ETA
4    *001*085*             *alpha*delta*                 001-alpha, 085-delta
```

I'm trying to concatenate the values in columns A and B into the following format under the result section. Anything helps, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula solution

Using `Textjoin` and `Filterxml` function, of which `Textjoin` available in Office 365 or Excel 2019 and `Filterxml` available in Excel 2013 & later versions of Excel

In `C2`, array formula (confirm by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter) copied down :

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFERROR(TEXT(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"*","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),"000")&FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,"*","</b><b>-")&"</b></a>","//b"),""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is doable with formulas but it might get unwieldy, so perhaps a UDF like this:

```
Public Function JoinNumbersAndSigns(ByVal numbersRng As Range, ByVal signsRng As Range) As String
    Dim nums As String
    nums = numbersRng.Cells(1).Value
    nums = Mid$(nums, 2, Len(nums) - 2) ' remove leading and trailing *

    Dim signs As String
    signs = signsRng.Cells(1).Value
    signs = Mid$(signs, 2, Len(signs) - 2) ' remove leading and trailing *

    Dim tempNums As Variant
    tempNums = Split(nums, "*")

    Dim tempSigns As Variant
    tempSigns = Split(signs, "*")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(tempNums) To UBound(tempNums)
        Dim tempString As String
        Dim sep As String

        tempString = tempString & sep & tempNums(i) & "-" & tempSigns(i)
        sep = ", "
    Next i

    JoinNumbersAndSigns = tempString
End Function
```

In Action:

[image]

The `nums = Mid$(nums, 2, Len(nums) - 2)` and similar line for `signs` could probably be made more robust, but should work given your current data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using regular expressions ...

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Link(vNumbers As Range, vSigns As Range) As Variant

    ' ADD REFERENCE TO "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"

    Dim vRegEx As New RegExp
    Dim vNumbersMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim vSignsMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim vCounter As Long

    ' The two parameters must only reference a single cell
    If vNumbers.Cells.Count <> 1 Or vSigns.Cells.Count <> 1 Then
        Link = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' use regular expression to get the numbers
    vRegEx.Pattern = "([0-9]+)"
    vRegEx.Global = True
    vRegEx.MultiLine = True
    Set vNumbersMatches = vRegEx.Execute(vNumbers.Text)

    ' Use regular expression to get the signs
    vRegEx.Pattern = "([^\*]+)"
    vRegEx.Global = True
    vRegEx.MultiLine = True
    Set vSignsMatches = vRegEx.Execute(vSigns.Text)

    ' If the number of Numbers and Signs differs, then return an error
    If vNumbersMatches.Count <> vSignsMatches.Count Then
        Link = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Loop through the Numbers and Signs, appending each set
    For vCounter = 0 To vNumbersMatches.Count - 1
        Link = Link & vNumbersMatches.Item(vCounter) & "-" & vSignsMatches.Item(vCounter) & IIf(vCounter < vNumbersMatches.Count - 1, " ,", "")
    Next

End Function
```

And the output ...

[image: image1]

Answer (score 0):

As long as there will always be a correlation between the number of elements in A & B this will work

```
Sub SplitandConcat()

' Declare working vars
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = 2
    Dim sOutputString As String
    Dim iWorkIndex As Integer
    Dim CommaSpace As String

While ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 1) <> ""

    CommaSpace = ""

    'Split the incoming string on delimiter
        arInput1 = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 1), "*")
        arInput2 = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 2), "*")

    ' For each non blank item in the 1st array join the corresponding item int the second
        For iWorkIndex = 0 To UBound(arInput1)
            If arInput1(iWorkIndex) <> "" Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 3) = ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 3) & CommaSpace & arInput1(iWorkIndex) & "-" & arInput2(iWorkIndex)
                CommaSpace = ", "
            End If
        Next iWorkIndex

' check next row
    lRow = lRow + 1
Wend
    
End Sub
```